# Haskell Fibonacci up to maximum specified number?

Tags: haskell

I have a Haskell function that's up and running, but it's doing the wrong thing.

It's supposed to output a Fibonacci sequence up to the maximum number specified.

Like this:

```
fibonacciSequence 86
1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 33 54
```

My code is currently outputting the first 10 numbers in a Fibonacci sequence instead of a Fibonacci sequence from 1 to 10.

It's outputting 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 33 54, but it should be 1,1,2,3,5,8.

```
fib :: Int -> Int
fib 0 = 0
fib 1 = 1
fib n = fib (n-1) + fib (n - 2)

---print (fib n)
fibList n = map fib[1..n]

main = 
do
putStrLn "The fibonacci series from 1 to n is:"
print (fibList 10)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: So test somewhere that what you're outputting is <= the maximum, and stop if it isn't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to take fibonacci numbers while they are less than 10, so:

```
fib 0 = 0
fib 1 = 1
fib n = fib (n-1) + fib (n-2)

fibList = map fib [0..]

takeWhile (<=10) fibList
```

---> `[0,1,1,2,3,5,8]`

Answer (score 8):

A more efficient way, is to generate an (infinite) list of Fibonnacci numbers:

```
fibs :: [Integer]
fibs = 0 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs)
```

then we can stop the list from the moment one of the lists is greater than 10 with [**`takeWhile :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:takeWhile):

```
takeWhile (<= 10) fibs
```

this is more efficient since we do not need to start from zero for each Fibonacci number. Furthermore it constructs the *k*-th item in *O(k)* time.

Comment: This is linear time, while the OP code is exponential time. This is way more efficient.